# New Users Identification

Tags: sql, clickhouse

working on transaction table where I need to add new and existing users and total transacting users.

Fields available,,

```
Txnid , customer_id (Unique identifier for single customer) ,added_on (timestamp)
```

how can I identify on daily basis number of new users transacted :

Query I tried for total unique customer :

```
select formatDateTime(bt.added_on,'%d-%m-%Y') as "date", 
count(distinct bt.customer_id) as "total transacting users"
from bill_transaction bt  
where bt.added_on > '2022-10-01 00:00:00'
group by 1
order by 1
```

The result I need :

[image]

Comment: formatDateTime() is not a standard PostgreSQL function, are you sure about PostgreSQL?

Comment: it's clickhouse

Comment: USERS is a synonym for CUSTOMER?

Comment: yes, customer_id is unique identifier for user